# asp.net fileupload server control performance

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I have a fairly simple `aspx` page (using a MasterPage) with various buttons and server-side event handlers. When I click the buttons the event handler is hit almost immediately. However, as soon as I add the following to my page:
asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUpload"" there is a huge increase in the delay between a button click and it's event handler, the fileUpload control is not used at this point.

I am struggling to find out where the delay in the process is so that I can try and bypass it. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As soon as you add what?

Comment: An asp:FileUpload control. Looks like this was stripped from my original post.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was related to McAfee DLP https://www.mcafee.com/uk/products/total-protection-for-data-loss-prevention.aspx

Whatever is added to the aspx page / viewstate by the fileUpload control caused our McAfee DLP to kick in and perform a whole bunch of checks before the page request was finally submitted.